# Splash Page: Email Collection (Rails 3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to programming and new to RoR.

I'm trying to build a simple email collection form for a splash page, but I'm getting an exception when I attempt to load the page in the browser. Below are the four relevant files:

**emails_controller.rb**

```
class EmailsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    render :layout => false
    @email = Email.new
  end

  def show
    email = Email.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**email.rb**

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :email, :presence   => true,
                :format     => { :with => email_regex },
                :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Splashtest::Application.routes.draw do
  get "emails/new"

  match 'splash', :to => 'emails#new'
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<h1>Get notified when we launch:</h1>

<%= form_for(@email) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here's the error I get when I load http://localhost:3000/splash:

> undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Please help me understand why I'm getting that error when I try and view the page. My goal is to save the email address in my database. I understand that more code is required to do that, but I'd like to get past this error first.

Answer (score 0):

```
def show
  @email = Email.find(params[:id])
end
```

You missed an `@`.

Comment: I missed a @, but I figured out what it was. I had to swap render :layout => false and @email = Email.new to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had to swap render :layout => false and @email = Email.new to get it to work.